# .htaccess for content language

Tags: html, .htaccess, lang

I am trying to figure out how to set the content language for a site that already exists. I do not have access to changing the HTML documents.

The website is set up in two languages.

The primary language in the main domain (xxx.com) is Spanish. All of the HTML documents declare the content language appropriately using `<html lang="es">`.

The secondary language is English, located in a subdirectory of the domain (xxx.com/en/). The content language is not declared in any of the HTML documents (just `<html>`). Apparently the developer thought it was unnecessary, but it is flagged as a problem in SEO testing.

I am trying to figure out how to fix this. I have found that a language declaration using `DefaultLanguage` or `AddLanguage` can be made in the .htaccess file (which I have access to modify). But I cannot find the ramifications in my searches.

If I add `DefaultLanguage en` to the `<IfModule mod_mime.c>` section of .htaccess:

1. Will it fix the problem of the missing language attribute in the /en/ subdirectory?
2. Will the lang="es" declaration in the main (Spanish) directory override the .htacess declaration, so that the content language remains correct?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain the system you are using? It sound's unlogical that you don't have access to the HTML files on the server, but that you can change the .htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry. I understand that it sounds contradictory. I am simply not permitted to alter the original HTML files.

Comment: @gce — Then it sounds like your real problem has nothing to do with programming and everything to do with bureaucracy

Comment: Perhaps. But it is what it is. That's why I'm looking for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

SEO is not my area of expertise and I don't know what your validator will be happy with but from the pure programming side the directives you mention both add a [Content-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Language) HTTP header, which kind of address your issue, but not quite (emphasis mine):

> For example, if **"Content-Language: de-DE"** is set, it says that the
>   document is intended for German language speakers (however, it **doesn't
>   indicate the document is written in German**. For example, it might be
>   written in English as part of a language course for German speakers.
>   If you want to indicate which language the document is written in, use
>   the lang attribute instead).

Additionally, [AddLanguage](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_mime.html#addlanguage) maps file extensions and languages; that doesn't match your use case. But you can try [DefaultLanguage](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_mime.html#defaultlanguage) and re-run your validator. The simplest way to set the scope is to save the `.htaccess` file inside the `en` subdirectory.

To rewrite the actual HTML you can try [mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) (once again, only in the context of the `en` subdirectory):

```
# Untested (I have no idea of escaping rules)
Substitute "s/<html>/<html lang=\"en\">/ni"
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the same documentation and found it a little confusing. I also get the impression from the various sources I consulted that the .htaccess directive might override the HTML language specification in the Spanish documents. That's why I'm hesitant, as the Spanish version is actually more important than the English one (I'm in Mexico).

Comment: What do you mean with override Spanish? I thought you meant the `en` subdirectory contained English documents with no `language` attribute :-?

Comment: As I explained, in the HTML documents, the only language specified is `lang="es"` in the Spanish version. The English version documents do not specify a language... which I am trying to rectify. So... if I specify in English as the Content Language in the .htaccess file, will it override the declaration of Spanish in the HTML documents? That is my concern.

Comment: If you save the `.htaccess` file inside the `en` subdirectory it'll affect every file there. If the directory contains mixed data you'll need a way to tell out Spanish files from English files. Files outside `en` will of course remain unaffected.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, the two HTML documents and all domain-internal resources are independent. It's just that the English website is in its own subdirectory. It sounds like a second .htaccess file applying only to that subdirectory will prevent any problems that might occur if the language declaration were placed in the main .htaccess file. Your help is appreciated.